# Buffer overflow - how a possibility of an attack is found?

Tags: security, buffer-overflow, exploit

I've been reading about buffer overflow exploits and I understand the concept (I know about a stack, overwriting a return address, a shell code, NOPs etc.)

All examples of exploits on youtube, in articles, in books refer to programs that are either stored locally, so you have a possibility to examine an exe file or are open source.

My question is: how does a hacker know that there is a possibility of an attack against a remote application (i.e software) and he/she can start sending malicious strings? How does he/she find an exploit?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the attack scenario. Usually in security, you assume the attacker knows everything about your system / security (except for your secrets i.e. encryption keys). Assume you're attacking an open source application. Then the software's code is known to everybody. A different scenario might be a closed-source software. Then you must reverse-engineer the program (once you get it) to  understand its logic.

There are many ways of getting samples of a targeted software. It is almost never impossible to achieve a sample of the targeted program either in some technical manner or through social engineering.

Answer (score 0):

Buffer-overflow attacks, when you don't have the source code available, are most often discovered by [fuzzing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzing). Fuzzing is the practice of sending invalid, random, or intentionally over-sized data to a system to see how it behaves. What you want to see as an attacker is a crash rather than an error. For a remote system, a crash generally looks like a 500 HTTP response code. That tells you that your data put the system into an undefined state. With that in hand, you can start crafting an attack to exploit that undefined state.

This is a reason to consider avoiding helpful return codes in the 400 and 500 range, perhaps only returning bare "400 - an error occurred" for any possible error. In some high-security systems, I've returned 404 errors for every possible problem. This makes things an incredible pain to debug, but it makes automated scanning more challenging. I'm not recommending this approach generally, but it is something to consider in higher-security systems.